# how to translate website right to left for arabic in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

1) I install the gtranslate plugin in my WordPress website and translate it in Arabic language but language only translate right to left not whole website I check another **pluginin** but they need to purchase for translate website like **plygon**, so it is possible using **gtranslate**. (I need only two language English and Arabic can I set also rtl tester on click on arbic using single click event call)

2) Can I set default language arabic using gtranslate wordpress plugin?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Stackoverflow topics. I would recommend contacting the plugin author for some support. You can try in Wordpress forums as well, make sure you post in the correct forum ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use qTranslate-X plugin as the original qTranslate has been discontinued.

According to [qTranslate-X documentation](https://qtranslatexteam.wordpress.com/faq/), the plugin supports RTL text, where it says:

> RTL should get enabled by WordPress based on locale of active language

Maybe you need to set `dir="rtl"` when the current language is arabic, for example something like this in the `<body>` tag:

```
<body<?php if(qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'ar') echo ' dir="rtl"' ?>>
```